# Lazy loading not working in EntityFramework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I have made the below properties as true.

```
Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
```

I have two classes :

```
 public partial class User : BaseEntity
    {
        public User()
        {
            this.UserRoles = new List<UserRole>();
        }

        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    }

public partial class UserRole : BaseEntity
    {
        public int UserRoleId { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
```

I am calling a stored procedure from EF 6 like this :

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetUserDetails(int? userId)
{
    var userIDParameter = userId.HasValue ?
    new SqlParameter("@UserId", userId) :
    new SqlParameter("@UserId", typeof(int));
    return _dbContext.Database
        .SqlQuery<User>("usp_GetUserDetails @UserId", userIDParameter);
}
```

Calling in Controller like this :

```
IEnumerable<User> user =  _storedProcedureService.GetUserDetails(5);
```

In my SP I have logic as :

```
Select * from User where UserId = @UserId
```

I get all the data related to `User` but `UserRoles.Count` comes as zero.

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: I revoked my comment as this SO thread says it is possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372288/how-do-linq-to-sql-stored-procedure-calls-work

Answer (score 4):

You are asking about using Lazy Loading with Entity Framework while you are using ADO.NET. ADO.NET does not support Lazy Loading, Entity Framework does.

For your info, this is ADO.NET;

```
var userIDParameter = userId.HasValue ?
                new SqlParameter("@UserId", userId) :
                new SqlParameter("@UserId", typeof(int));
return  _dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<User>("usp_GetUserDetails @UserId", userIDParameter);
```

Which uses `SqlParameter` and stuff like that.

This is Entity Framework;

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
    return db.User.Single(u => u.UserId = id);
}
```

Or, with stored procedures;

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
    return db.GetUserDetails(id);
}
```

If you want to let Entity Framework handle stored procedures *and* support Lazy Loading, I suggest you follow [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx).

Comment: The Database class is defined in System.Data.Entity which comes from EF. How it is related to ADO.Net ? In EF approach what you showed you are not using Stored Procedure, i need to use SP.

Comment: @user662285 When using `SqlQuery<>()`, you create raw queries which are not tracked by the context and thus are not lazy loaded. I suggest you also read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database(v=vs.113).aspx).

Comment: Whatever. It's not true that this is pure ADO.net. `Database.SqlQuery<User>` even creates dynamic proxies. They just don't lazy load, which other proxies from `DbSet`s do (even when not tracked). I'm not entirely sure, but I think this worked in previous EF versions, so this may be a bug or a breaking change.

Comment: @GertArnold Stored procedures work with lazy loading, just not the way the OP has implemented it. Perhaps you should also read the tutorial?

Comment: The choise to have `DbContext` expose `Database` as a public property has caused so much damage and confusion... the temptation for developers familiar with ADO.NET and its `SqlQuery` has led many astray.

Answer (score 1):

The answers so far completely miss the mark. It's incorrect to say that an *Entity Framework method* (`context.Database.SqlQuery<T>`) bypasses Entity Framework or that it's pure ADO.Net.

You use `SqlQuery<T>`. This is different than the database-first approach, in which a stored procedure is imported into an EDMX. An imported stored procedure is executed by a different method: [`ExecuteFunction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb739018%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). When this method is called and the result maps to an entity type, two things happen that don't happen when `context.Database.SqlQuery<T>` is executed.

1. The entities are tracked by the context's change tracker.
2. The entities perform lazy loading.

OK, two different methods present different behavior, why not? I could live with that. The only thing (and the answers overlook this fact) is that `context.Database.SqlQuery<T>` returns dynamic proxies when `T` is an entity type. **A dynamic proxy is expected to perform lazy loading.** That's one of the things it's made for. So to me it's unexpected that these two statements don't produce the same result:

```
var roles1 = _dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<User>(...).First().UserRoles;
var roles2 = _dbContext.Users.AsNoTracking().First(u => u.UserId == x).UserRoles;
```

Only the second statement performs lazy loading, but both create a proxy `User` entity. Maybe this is by design. Even so, it *is* confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You are using stored procedures to retrieve your user objects which bypass all the Entity Framework , you will need use Entity Framework to retrieve your user to have Entity Framework do its job. Something like the following.

```
_context.Set<Users>().Single(u=>u.UserId=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

The original post is correct.  SQLQuery is an EF method but it doesn't return an object that supports lazy loading.  Since it uses reflection to return the selected columns into the object the object key might not even be set.  In this case Child objects can't be identified.  The object returned **can't** be used like object.Parent.ID or object.Children.Count().